# 稀里糊涂and糊里糊涂, Are there any differences?

Tags: meaning, word

大家好！

1.稀里糊涂/糊里糊涂，它们有区别吗？
2.稀，里是什么意思？These are words not found in most dictionaries.

Comment: is it difficult?？

Answer (score 1):

The two differ in the "state of the subject" they describe. Both mean the subject is out of the ordinary, lacks order, and clarity.

"**糊里糊涂**" describes a person's thought processing ability (mental state) is out of order that results in his/her performance below the expected norm. Or lack of, the ability to process thought orderly and express it in a clear manner, the mental sharpness to remember details.

這個人總是糊里糊涂的弄不清狀況. 這個人做事總是糊里糊涂丟三落四的.

It started from the story that describes a mason plastering the wall by pasting the plaster in a random manner (糊涂) with a poorly prepared plaster paste (糊里) - 糊 is the plaster paste,  里 is 處理. Later it was used to describe a person who displays subpar mental sharpness.

"**稀里糊涂**" describes the disturbed state of a mixture/thing that was stirred out of the orderly form (physical state).

這件事被搞的稀里糊涂的.

It started from the event that a person boiling the dumpling for dinner, instead of leaving the dumplings boil naturally, he stirred them hardly and relentlessly, resulting in a pot of mixture that consisted of the fractured dumpling skins, the unrecognizable infill materials, and dense flour soup. In here, (稀里) means "in the soup". (糊涂) has a similar meaning as explained in the previous story. Combined, it means mixing the soup with lousy paste, which clearly is a "mess".

Answer (score 0):

[糊里糊涂](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E8%83%A1%E8%A3%A1%E8%83%A1%E5%A1%97): 形容人行事極為迷糊或不明道理 (describes people acting extremely confused or unreasonable)

[唏哩花啦](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E5%94%8F%E5%93%A9%E8%8A%B1%E5%95%A6): 1. 形容物體滾落、撞擊的聲音 (describe the sound of objects rolling down and hitting)  2. 比喻破敗難堪的情境 (metaphor of dilapidated and embarrassing situation)

稀里糊涂 sounds like the combination of the two (confused and embarrassing)

*唏哩花啦 has no meaning on their own in the idiom, they are sound effect characters*

Comment: 稀，里是什么意思？谢谢！！！！

Comment: 稀，指这行为不符合自己平时的习惯，少见的，表示未经过认真考虑，如果有人和你讨论这事，那很可能你就不会这么做了。

Comment: What does 里 mean in 稀里糊涂?

Answer (score 0):

In general, 稀里糊涂 and 糊里糊涂 mean "not clear" or "not precise." They are both used to describe something that is not clear or precise because the speaker is not sure of what they are saying.

However, there are some differences in their usage. 稀里糊涂 is more often used to describe a situation in which the speaker is not sure of the details, while 糊里糊涂 is more often used to describe a situation in which the speaker is not sure of the overall picture.

Here are some examples:

稀里糊涂: I'm not sure what happened exactly, but it was a big mess.

糊里糊涂: I'm not sure what the situation is, but it doesn't look good.